# Three Word Train

Tags: knowledge

> I am looking for 3 words in the form AB, BC, CA where A, B, and C are strings of letters. The words should satisfy the following descriptions.
>
> AB:
>   - figure from Greek mythology who is also famous for shrugging his shoulders
>
> BC:
>   - word of Western European roots referring to a young woman
>
> CA:
>   - a really hard problem or some collection of easier problems

Comment: It's not a train, it's a ring

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm thinking:

AB - figure from Greek mythology who is also famous for shrugging his shoulders

> AB = atlas

BC = word of Western European roots referring to a young woman

> BC = lass

CA = a really hard problem or some collection of easier problems

> CA = SAT

Comment: this one was first :)

Answer (score 9):

I think the answer is:

> A = AT
>  B = LAS
>  C = S

So AB: 
- figure from Greek mythology who is also famous for shrugging his shoulders

> ATLAS  ("Atlas Shrugged" is a novel title)

BC: 
- word of Western European roots referring to a young woman

> LASS

CA: 
- a really hard problem or some collection of easier problems

> SAT - either the complex Boolean satisfiability problem OR a collection of easier problems for college entrance exams